# Differentiating with respect to a vector transpose

Tags: matrix-calculus, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

Suppose a normal random regression model. Then the normal equations by the method of least squares expressed in matrix forms look like:
$$Q=(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)$$ where Q is the quantity we would like to minimize to get the least square estimates. Y is a ($n$ x 1) vector, X is a ($n$ x 2) matrix, and $\beta$ is a (2 x 1) vector.

To actually obtain the least square estimates, we need to differentiate Q with respect to $\beta$ as follows:

1. First expand the quantity Q:
   $$Q=Y^TY-\beta^TX^TY-Y^TX\beta+\beta^TX^TX\beta$$
2. Utilize $Y^TX\beta = \beta^TX^TY$ and manipulate terms:
   $$Q=Y^TY-2\beta^TX^TY+\beta^TX^TX\beta$$
3. Then take the derivative of Q with respect to $\beta$ and equate the result to the zero vector, $0$:
   $${\partial Q\over\partial\beta}=-2X^TY+2X^TX\beta=0$$

However, I can't see how the vector transpose $\beta^T$ disappeared in the above equation when the derivative was taken with respect to $\beta$ for Q.

I believe the steps I am missing are in elementary matrix calculus, but how do you differentiate an equation that contains both $\beta^T$ and $\beta$ in its terms (for example, $Q=Y^TY-2\beta^TX^TY-\beta^TX^TX\beta$ in our earlier example) with respect to a vector $\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a basic result of matrix calculus. For a vector $x$ and symmetric matrix $A$ you have
$$
\frac{\partial }{ \partial x} x' A x = 2x'A.
$$

You can derive this result by writing explicitly the quadratic form $x' A x$, i.e., 
$$
x'A x = \sum_i \sum_j x_i x_j a_{ij} = \sum x_i^2a_{ii} + 2\sum_{i > j}x_i x_ja_{ij},
$$ 
now by taking partial derivative w.r.t. to $x_k$  you'll get 
$$
\frac{\partial }{ \partial x_k} x'Ax = 2 x_k a_{kk} + 2 \sum_{i \neq k} x_ia_{ik} = 2 x ^ T a_{\cdot k},
$$
where $a_{\cdot k}$ is the $k$th column of $A$. Doing th same for every $k$, you'll get 
$$
2x^TA.
$$
In least square derivation $x = \beta$, and $A = X'X$, and instead of a row vector you're working with a column vector (the derivation is w.r.t. $\beta ^ T$), but the procedure is the same.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on "instead of a row vector you're working with a column vector (the derivation is w.r.t $\beta^T$)" because the $x$ vector in ${\partial\over\partial x}x^TAx=2x^TA$ in your answer looks like a column vector to me?

Comment: I'm confused as to If $x$ was a row vector like you suggested, wouldn't the A matrix in ${\partial\over\partial x}x^TAx=2x^TA$ end up having a (1x1) dimension and become a scalar (and we don't want A to be a scalar)?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone knows, the dot product of two vectors $\,(x,y\in{\mathbb R}^n)\,$ is commutative 
$$x\cdot y = y\cdot x$$
But when restated in matrix notation, it looks odd to claim that $$x^Ty=y^Tx$$
probably because we are so alert to the non-commutative behavior of matrices, for which it is definitely **not** true, i.e. 
$$X^TY \ne Y^TX$$
Given the function $\,\,\phi=y\cdot x,\,$ the gradient wrt $x$ is 
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}=y$$
and remains so, whether you **choose** to write the function as a dot product or a matrix product 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= x^Ty=y^Tx = y\cdot x \cr\cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

The plain simple answer is that the Differentiation of $β^T$($X^T$X)B becomes ($X^T$X)$\hat \beta$ ($\hat \beta$ is the Beta estimate)

$B^T$ disappears as usual.
`